# how to create reporst based on bank entries in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a bankbook app where I have a list of bank entries

It has been a week that I have started learning with logical examples...

now in a screen I want 3 types of data

1. Year report(includes CashIn total and CashOut total)

2. ) Month report(includes Cashin total and CashOut total)

3. daily report(includes Cashin total and CashOut total)

so here I have created a method for fetching report based on given year,month and day

if there is better way suggest me...I want to create in single method rather than 3 particular methods for year, month and day

Thanks in Advance...

```
class PassBookEntry
{
  
  double amount;
  bool isDeposite;
  DateTime date;

  PassBookEntry({required this.amount, this.isDeposite=false,required this.date});

}

List<PassBookEntry> _allEntries=[
  PassBookEntry(amount: 10 , date: DateTime(2023,08,11)),
  PassBookEntry(amount: 20,  date: DateTime(2023,08,11)),
  PassBookEntry(amount: 30, date: DateTime(2023,08,12)),
  PassBookEntry(amount: 100,  date: DateTime(2023,08,12),isDeposite: false),

];

Map<String,dynamic> getReport({required int year,int? month,int? day})
{
  double cashInTotal=0;
  double cashOutTotal=0;
  double balance=0;

  // looking for best code 

  return {
    'cashInTotal':cashInTotal,
    'cashOutTotal':cashOutTotal,
    'balance':cashInTotal-cashOutTotal,
  };


}
void main()
{
  var x=getReport(year: 2023,month: 8,day: 12);
  print(x['balance']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String,dynamic> getReport({required int year,int? month,int? day})
{
 
  double balance=0;

  double cashInTotal = 0;
  double cashOutTotal = 0;

  // Filter by year, month, and day
  for (var entry in _allEntries) {
    
    if (entry.date.year == year &&
        (month == null || entry.date.month == month) &&
        (day == null || entry.date.day == day)) {
      if (entry.isDeposite) {
        cashInTotal += entry.amount;
        print(cashInTotal);
      } else {
        cashOutTotal += entry.amount;
         print(cashOutTotal);
      }
    }
  }


  return {
    'cashInTotal':cashInTotal,
    'cashOutTotal':cashOutTotal,
    'balance':cashInTotal-cashOutTotal,
  };


}
```

This is a simple logic for the filter. There maybe edge cases but this would work.
If month is null then logic would match. Same goes for day